# Блокируется порт UDP при запуске сервера на Go с целью получения пакетов каждым экземпляром программы

Tags: golang, udp

Написал для тестов простейший UDP сервер на Go. Запускаю один экземпляр - все отлично, ловит broadcast пакеты, работает. Но! При запуске второго экземпляра приложения выдает ошибку `listen udp 0.0.0.0:10001: bind: address already in use`.

Погуглив и полазив по исходникам пакета net выяснил, что SO_REUSEADDR устанавливается и все должно бы работать хорошо, но не тут то было.

Подскажите, **что я делаю не так?**

Листинг:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

/* A Simple function to verify error */
func CheckError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
}

func main() {
    /* Lets prepare a address at any address at port 10001*/
    ServerAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "0.0.0.0:10001")
    CheckError(err)

    /* Now listen at selected port */
    ServerConn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", ServerAddr)
    CheckError(err)
    defer ServerConn.Close()

    buf := make([]byte, 1024)

    for {
        n, addr, err := ServerConn.ReadFromUDP(buf)
        fmt.Println("Received ", string(buf[0:n]), " from ", addr)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
        }
    }
}
```

go version:

```
go version go1.6.2 linux/amd64
```

lsb_release -a:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

uname -a:

```
Linux home-PC 4.4.0-83-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 17:54:43 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

UPD:
Немного пошаманив, нашел что можно определить переменную SO_REUSEPORT и на моем Linux она равна 15 (так себе решение, но вариантов больше не вижу). Определил, изменил пример на вот такой:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "log"
  "os"
  "syscall"
  "time"
)

const (
  SO_REUSEPORT int = 15
)

func main() {
  s, err := syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_INET, syscall.SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  syscall.SetsockoptInt(s, syscall.SOL_SOCKET, syscall.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
  syscall.SetsockoptInt(s, syscall.SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
  //  syscall.SetsockoptInt(s, syscall.SOL_SOCKET, syscall.SO_REUSEPORT, 1) // remove this line when you run linux
  lsa := &syscall.SockaddrInet4{Port: 12345, Addr: [4]byte{0, 0, 0, 0}}
  err = syscall.Bind(s, lsa)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  syscall.SetNonblock(s, true)
  rsa := &syscall.SockaddrInet4{Port: 12345, Addr: [4]byte{0, 0, 0, 0}}
  fin, ack := make(chan bool), make(chan bool)
  go reader(s, fin, ack)
  for i := 1; i <= 30; i++ {
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    syscall.Sendto(s, []byte(fmt.Sprintf("%v (%.02d)", os.Getpid(), i)), 0, rsa)
  }
  fin <- true
  <-ack
  fmt.Println("\nbye then")
}

func reader(s int, fin <-chan bool, ack chan<- bool) {
  rb := make([]byte, 32)
  for {
    n, _, err := syscall.Recvfrom(s, rb, 0)
    //    n, _, err := syscall.Recvfrom(s, rb, syscall.MSG_PEEK)
    if err != nil {
      time.Sleep(time.Second / 1000000)
    } else {
      fmt.Print(string(rb[:n]), "\n")
    }
    select {
    case <-fin:
      ack <- true
      return
    default:
    }
  }
}
```

Результат: два экземпляра приложения успешно биндятся на один порт. Присмотрелся у выводу и обнаружил, что последнее запущенный экземпляр захватывает сокет на чтение. Получается, что никто кроме него читать из сокета больше не может.

Снова вопрос: **Что я упускаю?**

Comment: Насколько мне известно, биндиться можно только один раз. `SO_REUSEADDR` - не про это.

Comment: @Ainar-G, Насколько известно мне, Вы не правы. По крайней мере в C/C++ можно регулировать этот момент с помощью именно SO_REUSEADDR

Comment: [Откуда взяты примеры из вопроса.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/fFO2aaOkp7o/frVEEqqdW64J) Там же есть обсуждение.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы иметь возможность повторно использовать порты, нужно задать параметры сокета. Если пишете под Linux, то можно использовать вот такую конструкцию:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "syscall"

    "golang.org/x/net/ipv4"
)

func main() {
    prog := "mcast_listener"

    if len(os.Args) != 5 {
        fmt.Printf("usage:   %s interface protocol group     address:port\n", prog)
        fmt.Printf("example: %s eth2      udp      224.0.0.9 0.0.0.0:2000\n", prog)
        return
    }

    ifname := os.Args[1]
    proto := os.Args[2]
    group := os.Args[3]
    addrPort := os.Args[4]

    mcastRead(ifname, proto, group, addrPort)
}

func mcastRead(ifname, proto, group, addrPort string) {
    addr, port := splitHostPort(addrPort)
    p, err1 := strconv.Atoi(port)
    if err1 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err1)
    }

    a := net.ParseIP(addr)
    if a == nil {
        log.Fatal(fmt.Errorf("bad address: '%s'", addr))
    }

    g := net.ParseIP(group)
    if g == nil {
        log.Fatal(fmt.Errorf("bad group: '%s'", group))
    }

    ifi, err2 := net.InterfaceByName(ifname)
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err2)
    }

    c, err3 := mcastOpen(a, p, ifname)
    if err3 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err3)
    }

    if err := c.JoinGroup(ifi, &net.UDPAddr{IP: g}); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := c.SetControlMessage(ipv4.FlagTTL|ipv4.FlagSrc|ipv4.FlagDst|ipv4.FlagInterface, true); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    readLoop(c)

    c.Close()
}

func splitHostPort(hostPort string) (string, string) {
    s := strings.Split(hostPort, ":")
    host := s[0]
    if host == "" {
        host = "0.0.0.0"
    }
    if len(s) == 1 {
        return host, ""
    }
    return host, s[1]
}

func mcastOpen(bindAddr net.IP, port int, ifname string) (*ipv4.PacketConn, error) {
    s, err := syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_INET, syscall.SOCK_DGRAM, syscall.IPPROTO_UDP)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err := syscall.SetsockoptInt(s, syscall.SOL_SOCKET, syscall.SO_REUSEADDR, 1); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // syscall.SetsockoptInt(s, syscall.SOL_SOCKET, syscall.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)

    if err := syscall.SetsockoptString(s, syscall.SOL_SOCKET, syscall.SO_BINDTODEVICE, ifname); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    lsa := syscall.SockaddrInet4{Port: port}
    copy(lsa.Addr[:], bindAddr.To4())

    if err := syscall.Bind(s, &lsa); err != nil {
        syscall.Close(s)
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    f := os.NewFile(uintptr(s), "")
    c, err := net.FilePacketConn(f)
    f.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    p := ipv4.NewPacketConn(c)

    return p, nil
}

func readLoop(c *ipv4.PacketConn) {

    log.Printf("readLoop: reading")

    buf := make([]byte, 10000)

    for {
        n, cm, _, err1 := c.ReadFrom(buf)
        if err1 != nil {
            log.Printf("readLoop: ReadFrom: error %v", err1)
            break
        }

        var name string

        ifi, err2 := net.InterfaceByIndex(cm.IfIndex)
        if err2 != nil {
            log.Printf("readLoop: unable to solve ifIndex=%d: error: %v", cm.IfIndex, err2)
        }

        if ifi == nil {
            name = "ifname?"
        } else {
            name = ifi.Name
        }

        log.Printf("readLoop: recv %d bytes from %s to %s on %s", n, cm.Src, cm.Dst, name)
    }

    log.Printf("readLoop: exiting")
}
```

Данный код можно запускать в несколько экземпляров и все они смогут слушать один и тот же порт.

Comment: Хороший пример, но... Multicast работает и так, а нужен именно broadcast

Comment: Тогда вам *не* нужен SO_REUSEPORT, так как эта опция именно нужна для получения пакетов по очереди: "[SO_REUSEPORT distributes datagrams evenly across all of the receiving threads](https://lwn.net/Articles/542629/)"

Answer (score 0):

Насколько можно понять из обсуждения, вы хотите чтобы один и тот же поток пакетов обрабатывало несколько программ, получая их напрямую от ядра. Однако это не то, что можно делать с помощью обычного API для серверов, так как опция `SO_REUSEPORT` подразумевает распределение нагрузки между процессами, а не получение всех данных и одним, и другим процессом.

Более того, в Linux предпринимаются меры [чтобы тот же процесс получал все пакеты, отправленные тем же хостом](https://lwn.net/Articles/542629/), потому вам может быть вообще не нужно то, что вы хотите сделать. (Например, если хост А и хост Б соединились с процессами В и Г соответственно, то процессы В продолжит получать все следующие пакеты от хоста А, а процесс Г - от хоста Б.)

Если же то, что вы хотите сделать, нужно по какой-то другой причины, не для того, чтобы обеспечить чтобы каждый процесс обрабатывал всегда только свои пакеты, то вам нужно идти глубже, опускаясь на уровень API ниже, [захватывая пакеты прямо на интерфейсе](https://github.com/ghedo/go.pkt). Конечно, вам придётся делать ту работу, которую обычно за вас делает ядро, но если очень нужно - это вариант.